# Create a Log with Unity and AOP

Tags: c#, logging, unity-container, aop

im trying to create a logger with Microsoft Unity and AOP, but something does not work... I do not understand what.. I just know that i Do not log anything.

Here the code for the logger:

```
public class LoggerHandler : ICallHandler
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        //The code to write a file 

        return result;
    }

    ...
}
```

Here I create the attribute:

```
//create an attribute so you can apply it to your methods  
public class LoggerAttribute : Attribute
{
    public LoggerAttribute()
    {
         //Here I have a breakpoint just to understand if i go here. I never stop here
    }
}
```

Here an helper to configure the interceptor via web.config

```
public class GetTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return Type.GetType(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

And here the web.config

```
<types>                    
     <type type="en.MFS.BLL.Countries.ICountries, en.MFS.BLL.Countries"
                      mapTo="en.MFS.BLL.France.FranceBLL, en.MFS.BLL.France">

         <interceptor type="TransparentProxyInterceptor" />
     </type>
</types>

<extension type="Interception" />
<interception>
    <policy name="LoggerPolicy">
         <matchingRule name="TransactionMatchingRule" type="CustomAttributeMatchingRule">
             <constructor>
                  <param name="attributeType" type="System.Type">
                    <value value="en.MFS.LoggerInterception.LoggerAttribute"                               typeConverter="en.MFS.LoggerInterception.GetTypeConverter, en.MFS.LoggerInterception"/>
                  </param>
                  <param name="inherited" value="true" />
             </constructor>
        </matchingRule>
        <callHandler name="LoggerHandler"
                          type="en.MFS.LoggerInterception.LoggerHandler, en.MFS.LoggerInterception" >
                <property name="Order" value="1" />
        </callHandler>
     </policy>
</interception>
```

And in the end how I use it

```
[Logger]
GetCalculation_OutDTO GetCalculation(GetCalculation_InDTO calculationDTO);
```

So, what's wrong? Why I do not manage to go in the constructor of the LoggerAttribute?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've done this using Unity, I've inherited the attribute from the special HandlerAttribute class instead of the more generic Attribute class.  Doing so will allow you to override the CreateHandler method and return an instance of your handler:

```
public class LoggerAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return new LoggerHandler();
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you should be able to wire it up in the Unity bootstrapper like this:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

container.Configure<Interception>().SetInterceptorFor<IInterfaceName>(new InterfaceInterceptor());

return container;
```

I'm not sure what's going on with the web.config, but I don't have anything in mine and the process outlined here works fine.